# Get last obj value of same type in json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON Data and i need last obj value from same type obj values.

I want to **Get last index of Foo value Bar**.

I know how to get last index of json array.

```js
var data = [{
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar-1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar-2"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar-1"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "foo": "bar-1"
  },

]



$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  if (val.foo == "bar") {
    console.log(key);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not a great duplicate

Comment: @mplungjan Then perhaps, instead of answering the question, you can help find the duplicate. Because there is one.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - that took longer than to write an answer :)

Comment: @anuj, what do you need to do next, since you believe you need jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery, just loop in reverse:

Assuming the element you want IS near the end. If not, then any of the reduce or map answers given will likely not be much slower

```js
var data = [
  {"foo": "bar"},
  {"foo": "bar-1"},
  {"foo": "bar-2"},
  {"foo": "bar-1"},
  {"foo": "bar"},
  {"foo": "bar-1"} // no comma on the last
]


// Find the last `bar`

for (var i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
  if (data[i].foo == "bar") {
    console.log('Last of Foo Bar is ' +i);
    break;
  }
}

// Find the last `bar` AND the last bar-1
var bars = { "bar":-1, "bar-1":-1, "done":0 }, numBars = 2;
for (var i=data.length-1;bars["done"]<numBars && i>=0;i--) {
  if (bars[data[i].foo]==-1) {
    bars[data[i].foo] = i;
    bars["done"]++;
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(bars));
```

Comment: but i need jquery each loop as i need to do further work.. btw thanks for solution :)

Comment: Using `$.each` makes no difference - you're looping over an array of objects. jQuery is irrelevant, and in this case, more redundant.

Comment: This is the most efficient answer, I've removed mine to reduce noise. Too much overthinking from me. :)

Comment: @IanStanley however your solution was the best of the non-efficient ones ;)

Comment: @IanStanley I also now realise that if the element wanted is the first or near the beginning, then your code will likely not be much slower

Comment: @mplungjan in case if i need to find bar and bar-1 then what should i need to do?

Comment: See update.............

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `reduce()` and when element is found set accumulator value to index of that element. So then index of last element found will be returned.

```js
var data = [{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"bar-1"},{"foo":"bar-2"},{"foo":"bar-1"},{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"bar-1"}]

var lastIndex = data.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if(e.foo == 'bar') r = i
  return r;
}, null)

console.log(lastIndex)
```

Comment: This will also take longer than just reverse looping

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, your solution is more efficient for this specific task, but maybe op need to loop all elements for some reason.

Comment: He says he does need jQuery for some reason. I would like to know what else he wants to do

Comment: Also if the last bar is near the beginning, my code will also have to look at them all

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use `jQuery` to solve it.

```js
var data = [{foo:"bar"},{foo:"bar-1"},{foo:"bar-2"},{foo:"bar-1"},{foo:"bar"},{foo:"bar-1"}],
    indexes = [];
    data.forEach((v,i) => v.foo == 'bar' ? indexes.push(i) : v);

console.log(`Index of last 'bar' key is ${indexes[indexes.length-1]}`);
```

Comment: Again that will take much longer than just reverse looping

Comment: @mplungjan *Much longer*. Oh, please.

Comment: Of course with the array in OP's example it does not matter, However we have no way of knowing how big the actual array is. Never assume that the example matches reality. You could be creating thousands of items just to find the last of the ones your pushed.

Comment: @mplungjan I just mean that it would be perceptible only for very huge arrays. In this particular case, it doesn't really matter. But I also agree with you, we can't just assume that OP won't use it for bigger variables. (: